# How to validate data of two models in the django-admin when using inlines?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

**Update**: Reading directly the django source code i got one undocumented missing piece to solve my problem. Thanks to Brandon that solved half of the problem by giving me one of the missing pieces. See my own answer to see my solution (i dont want to mix things here).

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
Order(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField( max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='PENDING')
    total = models.DecimalField( max_digits=22, decimal_places=2)

    def clean(self):
        if self.estatus == 'PAID' or self.estatus == 'SENT':
            if len(self.payment.all()) > 0:
                raise ValidationError("The status cannot be SENT or PAID if there is no payment for the order")

Payment(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField( max_digits=22, decimal_places=2 )
    order  = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="payment")

    def clean(self):
        if self.amount < self.order.total or self.amount <= 0:
            ValidationError("The payment cannot be less than the order total")
```

In my admin.py i have:

```
class paymentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model   = Payment
    max_num = 1

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model   = Order
    inlines = [ paymentInline, ]
```

The validation in the clean method of the Order does not work because there is no payment saved when the validation occurs (obviously it has not been saved to the database).

The validation inside the payment works fine (if editing or adding a new payment).

I want to validate if the order has a payment if the status is 'PAID' or 'SENT', but as i cannot doit the way is in the clean method.

My question is, how can i access the 'payment.amount' value entered by the user in the inline (payment) of the Order form, to accomplish my validation? (considering im in the clean method of the Order model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the django source code i found one property of the BaseInlineFormSet that contains the Parent Instance of the Inline, in my case, the Order instance being edited.

Brandon gave me another important piece, iterating over the self.forms of the BaseInlineFormSet to get each of the instances (even not saved or not cleaned or empty), in my case, each Payment Instance being edited.

These are the two pieces of information needed to check if the Order with status 'PAID' or 'SENT' has a payment or not. Iterate over the cleaned_data of the formset would not give Order data (i.e. when not changing the Order, just changing the Payment, or when not adding a Payment -and an empty Payment- but changing the Order) which is needed to decide to save the model if the order status is different than 'PAID' or 'SENT', so this method was discarded before.

The models are keep the same, I only modified the admin.py to add the next:

```
class PaymentInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        order = None
        payment = None

        if any(self.errors):
            return

        # django/forms/models.py Line # 672,674 .. class BaseInlineFormSet(BaseModelFormSet) . Using Django 1.3
        order = self.instance

        #There should be only one form in the paymentInline (by design), so  in the iteration below we end with a valid payment data.
        if len(self.forms) > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Only one payment per order allowed.')
        for f in self.forms:
            payment = f.save(commit=False)

        if payment.amount == None:
            payment.amount = 0

        if order != None:
            if order.status in ['PAID', 'SENT'] and payment.amount <= 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'The order with %s status must have an associated payment.'%order.status)

class pymentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model   = Payment
    max_num = 1
    formset = PaymentInlineFormset

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ paymentInline, ]

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(Payment)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to validate that there is at least one valid formset in the inlines...you might give this code a try: http://wadofstuff.blogspot.com/2009/08/requiring-at-least-one-inline-formset.html

Hope that gets you going.

[Edit]

I took a look at some code I had written for another app that had custom validation on inlines based on a property on the related model. Of course, you may need to make some adjustments, but give this a try. You'll need to specify an inline to use in your admin model too.

```
#I would put this in your app's admin.py
class PaymentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Payment
    formset = PaymentInlineFormset

#I would put this in the app's forms.py
class PaymentInlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
        def clean(self):
            order = None
            valid_forms = 0

            for error in self.errors:
                if error:
                    return

            for cleaned_data in self.cleaned_data:
                amount = cleaned_data.get('amount', 0)
                if order == None:
                    order = cleaned_data.get('order')
                if amount > 0:
                    valid_forms += 1

            if order.status in ['PAID', 'SENT'] and len(valid_forms) > 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Your error message')
```

Comment: I only need to requiere the valid formset in the inlines when the status of the Order is 'PAID' or 'SENT'. Any other statuses may let the user save the model without the inline data (empty one). The problem is how to access these fields (data) from each model form (the main model being edited, and the inline one) to compare them.

Comment: It should be possible to get a reference to the parent object that the inlines are related to. I'll see if I can get a working sample going for you tomorrow.

Comment: I added an edit showing a custom inline formset that might work for you.

Comment: self.cleaned_data is empty: [{}]

Comment: When no data in the Payment (leave empty) self.cleaned_data is empty, I was thinking it was going to be populated with Order cleaned_data, but it is the PaymentInlineFormSet.

Comment: After further testing, I realised that it is the same result as having the clean method in the Payment Model. This Still cannot validate in the case the Order has a 'PAID' status but the user leave the Payment empty (because the cleaned_data is empty).

Comment: You might try looping through self.forms instead of cleaned data to get at the values. Getting at the Order may be such that you have to do an ORM call and use the primary key contained in self.forms['order']

Comment: Yes, iterating over the self.forms gives me one piece i need (the Payment data even not cleaned). After some time reading django code, i found an undocumented property of BaseInlineFormSet, so i could get the missing information needed to complete my task. I will edit my question to update it with my final code. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I'm interested to see what you found.