# django validate multiple inline forms

Tags: django, forms, validation

I'm using the Django admin interface and Modelform form validation.

I'm having an issue for one of my models, I can't figure out a way to have the inline forms check for uniqueness on a field. For example there are two inline objects with the the field 'name'. I'd like to raise a validation error if both contain the same name.

From what I can see, each inline is validated as a separate form so its hard to tie them in and check for this.

(Very) basic idea:

```
Class Parent        
    name    charfield
    inlines [Child]

Class Child
    name    charfield   <- I'd like to make sure this is unqiue within the inlines
    age     intfield
```

Comment: It seems you can take a similar approach as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6645205/1267329

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write your own FormSet class, and make a clean callable:

```py
class BaseDateFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
'''run some validation on the forms dates values'''

    def clean(self):
        super(BaseDateFormSet, self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return
        for form in self.forms:
            start_date = form.cleaned_data.pop('start_date', None)
            end_date = form.cleaned_data.pop('end_date', None)

            if start_date and end_date:
                if start_date >= end_date:
                    raise ValidationError("The end date is before the start date.")
```

To use, pass into the formset factory:

```py
MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    <parent model class>, <model class>, extra=1, formset=BaseDateFormSet
)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks promising - I'll try and plug this in tomorrow. Can't get to the code right now

Comment: Note you can simply specify `formset = BaseDateFormSet` in your admin inline class definition.